# Norm of the Jacobian of a $C^1$ vector field is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Let $v:C\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a $C^1$-vectorfield, where $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. I want to prove that there is a constant $L>0$ such that $$\lvert Dv_u \cdot w\rvert \leq L\cdot\lvert w \rvert$$ for all $u\in C$ and $w\in \mathbb{R}^m$, where $Dv_u$ denotes the jacobian of $v$ at $u$. By using the unit sphere S=$\{w\in \mathbb{R}^m:\lvert x\rvert=1\}$, the linearity of $Dv_u$ and the Minimum-Maximum-Theorem, I can show that for every fixed $u\in C$ there exists an $L>0$ such that the inequality holds. How do i proof that there is an $L>0$ for every $u\in \mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: If $Dv_u$ is the Jacobian (a linear operator), what do you mean by taking a scalar product with a vector?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but if $f$ is $C^1$ and $u,v\in C$ then by Cauchy-Schwarz and the definition of the operator norm we have$$\| \left\langle Df(u)v,w \right\rangle \|\leq \|Df(u)v\|\|w\|\leq \|Df(u)\|\|v\|\|w\|.$$

Since $C$ is compact, $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous, and $u\mapsto Df(u)$ is continuous, the restriction of $u\mapsto \|Df(u)\|$ to $C$ attains a maximal value $L_1$. Likewise, the norm attains a maximal value $L_2$ on $C$. So you can take $L=L_1L_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on what you said, for each $u \in C$, you can find a small open neighbourhood $A_u$, and a constant $L_u$ such that the inequality holds. Note that the sets $\left\{ A_u\right\}_{u \in C}$ forms an open cover for $C$. By compactness, there's a finite subcover, say $\{A_{u_1}, \dots, A_{u_k}\}$. Simply take $L = \max\{L_{u_1}, \dots, L_{u_k}\}$.